# Output filter (pi filter) EAGLE design

Tags: filter, design, eaglecad

I am working on a project of wireless power transfer system for EVs. On the secondary side there is a full-wave rectifier which output current charges the battery. Of course, after the rectifier stage there needs to be a filter that will reduce load's current and voltage ripple (see the picture)

[image: secondary side of a WPT system]

Now, since I decided to use 'Pi filter' as an output filter, and have chosen the values of the inductance and the caps, I am not clear about few things when I want to build my schematic in EAGLE, because this is my first project and I am inexperienced in circuit design.

1) How should two caps and inductance be connected in the schematic between the rectifier stage and the load? Since I doubt that it will be a simple connection between one L and two C-s (there may have been some additional small caps and resistors)

2) What type of inductor should it be (common type, etc..)?

3) If I am not wrong, caps going to be used should be film capacitors.

Comment: Actually the caps your looking for will be C0G ceramics.  The circuits need to be stable under voltage and temperature variances.  You can get them with ratings in excess of 100nF at 5kV.  As for the inductor, they make power torrids that should work.  Depending on the level of ripple, you may not even need the inductor, just add more caps.

Comment: @GB-AE7OO wrong; X7R or X5R will probably do very well. He's not trying to "tune" to anything.

Comment: @GB-AE7OO an inductor is needed, because without it my current ripple is approx. 10 A, and with it the ripple decreases to .8 Amps. Are you sure that ceramics need to be used ?

Comment: @Andyaka  Sorry for the delay.  The caps should be electrolytics or you'll need to add damping to the filter.  This is a tank circuit and when using ceramics(low ESR) it will be under damped(understatement).  With the values given, it's -3dB and resonate freq is around 11Khz.  I would go with 2000uF on each side with a  4mH 15A inductor that is shunted by 2 ohms.  That gets you a cutoff around 38Hz that is stable.  Follow with a good common mode choke.

Comment: If this will used where it gets cold, I would bump the resistor 3 ohms.

Comment: Firstly cap of C2 must be mmkp type. for example: https://www.vishay.com/docs/28124/mmkp383.pdf
Additionally, when you used pi filter, most probably your system didn't work.